# Field values don't show up in the symbology while they are visible in attribute table

Tags: qgis, shapefile, symbology, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am trying to colour different categories within a shapefile in different styles to differentiate them - these categories are visible when looking in the shapefile's attribute table, but then don't show up when I try to alter the symbology by category.

The categories I'd like to use are the *Special Management Zone*, *General Management Zone* ones.

[image: What is visible in the symbology tab:]

[image: What is visible in the attribute table:]

Comment: Did not you forget to press the `Classify` button`?

Comment: i think u stopped half-way of the procedure @rk4478